# proper display but error shows during compile

Tags: errors

I havewritten the following code, the display is correct but the texmaker shows errors such us "missing $ inserted" and "display math should end with $$".

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,amsthm,cleveref}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Bbb H =\Bigg{ \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}

                                 1     & x_1 & x_3 \\
                                 0     & 1   & x_2 \\
                                 0     &0    & 1 
       \end{pmatrix}  \in GL(3,\mathbb{R})} : x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R} \Bigg \rbrace 


\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd use `\left\{ \right\}` to adjust the braces. But you can also use another fixed sizes, e.g. `\Biggl\{ \Biggr\}` (not so tall)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,amsthm,cleveref}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{H} = \left\{
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & x_1 & x_3 \\
   0 & 1   & x_2 \\
   0 & 0   & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \in GL(3,\mathbb{R}) : 
  x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R} 
 \right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding that the main error was the blank line inside the `equation` environment.